# text style is not updating at animation end

Tags: android, animation

i create animation, at the start of animation i am changing the styles of some button and then  and at the end of the animation i am changing buttons style back to its previous style but that's is not happing it still show the same style that was set at onAnimationStart()
 Every thing looks fine the control is also going through the loop in onActionEnd() but still no update in buttons style. Help Please

```
public void WrongAnim()
{

    AlphaAnimation animation = new AlphaAnimation(1, 0.5f);
    //animation.setRepeatCount(1);
    animation.setDuration(2000);

    animation.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener(){

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.v("Wronganim", "end...");
            for(int i=0; i<input_boxes.size(); i++)
            {
                input_boxes.get(i).getBox().setTextAppearance(context, R.style.textstyle);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.v("Wronganim", "start......");
            for(int i=0; i<input_boxes.size(); i++)
            {
                input_boxes.get(i).getBox().setTextAppearance(context, R.style.redtext);
            }
        }

    });

    inputbar.startAnimation(animation); //lienar layout inflate from xml

}
```

Comment: @Sameer this function is a member of a class which is non-activity class so runOnUiThread() is not availble here